# If two invertible matrices A and B commute, then A^-1 and B^-1 must commute as well ??

Tags: matrices, inverse

If two invertible matrices A and B commute, so their inverse must commute as well or not ?

Answer (score 6):

This follows from 
\begin{equation}
A^{-1}B^{-1} = (BA)^{-1} = (AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Can i have another question ?

Comment: Sure, what is it?

Comment: Is the equation (A+B)^2 =A^2+2AB+B^2 holds for all n*n matrices A and B ?

Comment: @Ramy: Nope... you have $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2$, and in general $AB \neq BA$.

Comment: @A.P. : Could you tell me why ? or it's proof ?

Comment: @Ramy Just expand the product: $(\color{red}{A} + \color{green}{B})(A + \color{grey}{B}) = \color{red}{A} A + \color{red}{A} \color{grey}{B} + \color{green}{B} A + \color{green}{B} \color{grey}{B}$. (I hope you're not colour-blind...)

Comment: @A.p.: Can i have another question ?

Comment: @Ramy Yes, if it is related to this. Otherwise you should ask a new one with the top right button (I promise I will take a look at it).

Comment: i think it's related somehow, is says If A is invertible matrix then does A^-1 * x =0 has non-trivial solutions ?

Comment: @Ramy It is not really related... Anyway, the answer is no, because $A(A^{-1} x) = A0 \iff x = 0$.